# MixItUp Portfolio Filter adds fail class

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/14577/create-a-simple-responsive-portfolio-page-with-filtering-and-hover-effect) to add a interactive portfolio to Yoothemes Zoo. When clicking on a category the items hide for a brief moment, but suddenly show up. And a "fail" class is added to the DIV with portfoliolist ID. [Here is the demo page.](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/simple-portfolio-page/index.html)

I think I implented everything correctly, but I can miss something.

[Here is the link to the page.](http://joomla.studiopannekoek.nl/portfolio)

THanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this with using the library that you can download directly from the mixitup site. Added this css;

```
#portfoliolist .mix{
    display: none;
}
```

And the following JS;

```
$(function(){
    // Instantiate MixItUp:
    $('#portfoliolist').mixItUp();
});
```